# mongodb getting data from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to see who did the comment by reaching users collection with commentedBy but it is not showing it. What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for help.

```
Comment.find()
    .populate("commentedBy")
    .then(p => console.log(p))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I want to see who did the comment by reaching users collection with commentedBy but it is not showing it. What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for help.
User

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        min: 3,
        max: 15,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        max: 50,
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 4,
        max: 15,
    },
    profilePic:{
        type: String,
        default:"https://icon-library.com/images/default-profile-icon/default-profile-icon-24.jpg"
    },
    followers:{
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    },
    followings:{
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    },
},{timestamps: true});


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  
    username:{
        type: String,
    },
    text:{
          type: String,
          max: 500,
          min: 10,
          required: true,
    likes:{
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    },
    dislikes:{
        type: Array,
        default: [],
    },
    commentedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "users"
    }
},{timestamps: true});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema);
```

Comment: can you show the user schema and model?

Comment: try `ref: "User"` in the comment schema

Comment: added  them on post

Comment: ref: "User"  didn't work neither @SuleymanSah

Comment: Did you update exactly like this `commentedBy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }`

Comment: Also CommentSchema is not valid, it should include de `{` like `CommentSchema({...`

Comment: I couldn't solve it but thank you @SuleymanSah